# Can't use M-x in ansi-term mode

Tags: key-bindings, ansi-term

When in `ansi-term`, i can't use `M-x`, the keyboard shortcut doesn't do anything. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 12):

Term mode has two input mode char mode and line mode. In char mode you would press `C-x M-x` (prefix your standard keyboard shortcuts with `C-x` [0]).

If you enter line mode (`C-c C-j` [1]) `M-x` should work as usual.

You can read more on both:

[0] https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html

Comment: Thanks, could you help me with something else? How can I cancel a process in ansi-term like i would with ctrl + c in a normal terminal outside of emacs?

Comment: C-c C-c will send a ctrl-c to the terminal.